# jQuery mobile: the styles for the next page are applied to the current page while making a server connection during page navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mobile

In our app, when we navigate between some pages we make server requests before proceeding to the next page. While this is happening there is a loading graphic displayed over the current page. What is odd is that the styles for the next page get applied to the current page while waiting for the server response to finish. This causes layout of the current page to change.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening, maybe by applying css styles for a page only when the page is actually visible?? Or is it just a case of making unique classes for each page so that there are no clashes?

Answer (score 0):

say you have index.html and index2.html as two pages,
now you create index.css and refer the same only in the index.html
similarly create index2.css and refer the same only in index1.html

edit after your comment
for reference [css priority](http://monc.se/kitchen/38/cascading-order-and-inheritance-in-css)
Internal style sheet the last declared has high priority.

Comment: This basically is the issue. We have shared containers across all pages, on some specific pages there are CSS overrides. Those overrides are being applied to the current page before the next page is actually visible. The result is that for a second or two while the loading animation runs the current page layout looks broken. Is there a way to fix this or is it just an issue with what we're doing or perhaps how jQuery mobile handles page navigation?

Comment: are you using ajax for loading data

Comment: you got to include only the required css files for the particular page,dont include the unintended css files. check updated answer